# Werden die Anlagen eines Briefes im Nominativ oder Akkusativ angegeben?

Tags: grammatical-case, letter

Ich hatte gerade ein Gespräch mit einem, nach meinem Eindruck, sehr gebildeten und die deutsche Sprache auf hohem Niveau benutzenden Menschen, der behauptete, dass man bei der Auflistung der Anlagen am Schluss eines Briefes den Akkusativ nutzt. Ich halte für den Nominativ für richtig, man zählt ja einfach nur die Dokumente auf.

Einzige mir einfallende Begründung für den Akkusativ wäre, dass "Anlagen" für "Ich habe ... beigelegt." steht.

Was ist nun richtig?

**Nominativ**

```
Anlagen
Mein Personalausweis
```

**Akkusativ**

```
Anlagen
Meinen Personalausweis
```

?

Annahme ist, dass ein Possessivartikel benötigt wird, weil in dem Brief auch  andere Personalausweise erwähnt werden.

Comment: None of these. Just use a list (- Personalausweis ...). Also I'd suspect that is not really your original Personalausweis, but a copy.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See last paragraph. I wrote, that it is required imho. I agree that it's actually a copy but I'll leave this inaccuracy since the question is about the case.

Comment: Ich muss bei meiner Antwort leider eine grammatikalische Referenz offen lassen. Aber bei der 2. Variante sträubt sich einfach Alles in mir. Das kann keinesfalls richtig sein.

Answer (score 6):

> Ich halte für den Nominativ für richtig, man zählt ja einfach nur die Dokumente auf.
>   ...
>   Annahme ist, dass ein Possessivartikel benötigt wird, weil in dem Brief auch andere Personalausweise erwähnt werden.

Wenn die Angabe (wie erwähnt) benötigt wird, dann ist der Nominativ korrekt:

> > Anlagen
> >      - **Mein** Personalausweis

---

Der Akkusativ macht ohne den weiteren Kontext eines Satzes wie z.B.

> > Ich habe **meinen** Personalausweis dem Schreiben beigelegt.

keinen Sinn in diesem Fall.

---

Allgemein werden beigefügte Anlagen zu einem Schreiben *ohne* Possesivpronomen aufgelistet:

> > Anlagen
> >     - Personalausweis (Kopie)
> >     - Führerschein (Kopie)
> >     ... etc

Comment: Since you've asked for a reference in a comment above, maybe DIN 5008 gives a clue. [here](https://piseite.de/anlagenverweis/bewerbung-705/) is an example